# Textarea for tagging (not HTML tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging

Googling for this is very, very frustrating. Whenever I search for the word tag and editor, or textarea, or textfield, I end up at some Wysiwyg editor for HTML.

But I'm looking for a javascript plugin which allows me to edit and add tags, in a form. Tags like below this post. You type in the first letters and get a selection of tags, or keywords, or whatever.

what I need is a similar drop-in jQuery plugin for a text-area. Tumblr had it, too, until they changed it recently.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you looking for is [here](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)...

Taginputs is easy to use, fully documented, built in jquery and fully customizable... simlilar to the stackoverflow's tag input..:)...

you can use both textarea or div to display the tags...

Answer (score 0):

You need the jQuery Autocomplete plugin.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/